# How to show data from other function into flask app

Tags: python, flask

I am new to python and flask. Can anyone help me on this

```
from flask import Flask
import logging

logging.basicConfig(filename="err.log",level=logging.DEBUG)

student = ['abcd', '001', '11']  # I want to extract list value from here and needs to display in flask app

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route("/")
def student_details():
    print("student: "+student[0])
    print("id: "+student[1])
    print("grade: "+student[2])

student_details()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(host='127.0.0.1', port="8000",debug=False)
```

Current Output: **Internal Server Error**

Desired Output:

> student: abcd
>
> id: 001
>
> grade: 11

Comment: You want the list elements to be printed on your webapp, ```print()``` function is used to print it on the console,you need to create html pages and use Jinja templates to print them on your browser.

Comment: @T.Square I am just learning flask and trying this on my own. since i did not get the result i posted my question here.

Answer (score 0):

Although I would suggest reading about how to make html pages and use Jinja templates with flask,  Use return instead of print. print() is used for printing on the console. You can also use a for loop to generate a string and then return it.

```
from flask import Flask
import logging

logging.basicConfig(filename="err.log",level=logging.DEBUG)

student = ['abcd', '001', '11']  # I want to extract list value from here and needs to display in flask app

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route("/")
def student_details():
    return "student " + str(student[0]) + " id " + str(student[1]) + " grade " + str(student[2])

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(host='127.0.0.1', port="8000",debug=False)
```

Comment: Thanks alot. Sure, I will HTML templates to show data in webapp.